# Can we get a spammer's profile details removed?

Tags: discussion

[This particular user](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/72145/halpern?tab=profile), account created today, was set up solely to spam (in my opinion at least).

Their one and only post so far was already deleted by our moderator(s), but links remain on their profile. Even if they never post again, I think that the site linked to in the user profile still provides some value to the spammer.

Is there a way for us to report an entire profile?
Is removing material from a user profile something our mods can do, or is that something that we'd need to appeal to a community manager for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I agree with you. I cleared out all reference to the "Love Calculator".

Comment: Thanks, Adrian!